# How to display a table when a button is clicked?

Tags: html, html-table

How can I remove the table and display it when I click the submit button with all the data entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give it an ID :

```
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

hide it initially :

```
document.getElementById('myTable').style.display = none;
```

when running the submit function, add :

```
document.getElementById('myTable').removeProperty('display');
```

Comment: Where should I add the hide statement?=

Comment: you have provided no code. How should I know? :) When you want to hide the table, add the `document.getElementById('myTable').style.display = none;`, and when ['click the submit button'] add the `document.getElementById('myTable').removeProperty('display');`. Without proper code samples, can't do anything more.

Comment: <html> <head </head> <body>  <script src="script.js"></script>  <form >    <br>   <br>   <b>Name:</b>   <input type="text" name="t1" id="na">   <br>   <br>   <b>ID Number:</b>   <input type="text" name="t2" id="id">   <br>   <br>   <b>Maths:</b>   <input type="Number" name="t3" id="ma">   <br>   <br>   <b>Physics:</b>   <input type="Number" name="t4" id="ph">   <br>   <br>   <b>Chemistry:</b>   <input type="Number" name="t5" id="ch">   <br>   <br>   <input type="button" onclick="details()" value="Submit">  </form>  <table id="table" style="width: 100%">   <tr>    <td>Name</td>    <td>ID</td>